# Need to change the label based on the row value in run time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

Need to add label for payment_type based on the condition if status "2" then "Cash" and for "1" - credit.

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azBn2.jpg)

This my javascript code:

```
/*
 * Editor client script for DB table odenis
 * Created by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
 */

(function($){

$(document).ready(function() {
    var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: 'php/table.odenis.php',
        table: '#odenis',
        fields: [
            {
                "label": "&Ouml;d\u0259ni\u015f &uuml;sulu:",
                "name": "usul",
                "type": "radio",
                "options": [
                { label: "Nəğd", value: "1" },
                { label: "Kontur", value: "2" }
                    //"1" ,
                    //"2" 
                ]

            },
            {
                "label": "&Ouml;d\u0259ni\u015f m&uuml;dd\u0259ti:",
                "name": "muddet",
                "type": "radio",
                "options": [
                { label: "Aylıq", value: "1" },
                { label: "Yığılsın deyərəm", value: "2" },
                { label: "10 günlük", value: "3" },
                { label: "Həftəlik", value: "4" },
                { label: "15 günlük", value: "5" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "&Ouml;d\u0259ni\u015f tarixi:",
                "name": "tarix",
                "type": "datetime",
                "format": "YYYY-MM-DD"
            },
            {
                "label": "&Ouml;d\u0259ni\u015f miqdar\u0131:",
                "name": "miqdar"
            }
        ]
    } );

    var table = $('#odenis').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        ajax: 'php/table.odenis.php',
        columns: [
            { 
                "data": "usul",

            },   
            {
                "data": "muddet"
            },
            {
                "data": "tarix"
            },
            {
                "data": "miqdar"
            }
        ],
        select: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'edit',   editor: editor },
            { extend: 'remove', editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
} );

}(jQuery));
```

and this is php:

```
<?php
$cariid = file_get_contents('../../cariid.txt');
/*
 * Editor server script for DB table odenis
 * Created by http://editor.datatables.net/generator
 */

// DataTables PHP library and database connection
include( "lib/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    DataTables\Editor\Options,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;

// The following statement can be removed after the first run (i.e. the database
// table has been created). It is a good idea to do this to help improve
// performance.
$db->sql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `odenis` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `obyekt_id` varchar(255),
    `usul` varchar(255),
    `muddet` varchar(255),
    `tarix` date,
    `miqdar` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY( `id` )
);" );

// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( $db, 'odenis', 'id' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'obyekt_id' )
            ->set( false ),
        Field::inst( 'usul' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'muddet' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'tarix' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::dateFormat', array( 'format'=>'Y-m-d' ) )
            ->getFormatter( 'Format::date_sql_to_format', 'Y-m-d' )
            ->setFormatter( 'Format::date_format_to_sql', 'Y-m-d' ),
        Field::inst( 'miqdar' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' )
    )
    ->where( 'obyekt_id', $cariid )
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

working fine in edit button(picture 2). But i need it in table also. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgiKK.jpg)

Comment: And how do you generate this table? Show your code.

Comment: i shared code and screenshots. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

İ solved by using render.

```
                data:"usul",
                render:function ( data, type, row ) {
                    var melumat = data;
                    if((type === "display" || type === "filter") && melumat ==1){  
                        return 'Nəğd';
                    }
                    else if((type === "display" || type === "filter") && melumat ==2){
                        return 'Kontur';
                    }   
                    else{
                        return data;
                    }

                }
```